# WPF ListView multi columns row

Tags: wpf, listview

I have this model:

```
Public Data
{
    string name;
    string age;
    string id;
    DateTime time;
}
```

Currently each `ListView` row contains  all this 4 peoperties:

```
<ListView.View>
        <GridViewColumn Width="20" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Index}" />
        <GridViewColumn Width="320" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}" />
        <GridViewColumn Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IPAddress}" />
        <GridViewColumn Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding time}" />
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Now i want to make this `ListView` `Width` smaller so i want to each `Row` will contain 2 columns with 2 properties on each of them.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the default CellTemplate of GridViewColumn inorder to display your results inside a ListView.View

```
<GridViewColumn >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>                            
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>                                    
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding IPAddress}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding time}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a ListView

Use a [ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx) [DataTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) with a Grid

Comment: Then put a Grid in a ListView.  I see nothing about this that requires a ListView.

Comment: What this Grid will give me ?